# How do I derive the alveolar gas equation?

Tags: derivation-of-formulae

I'm taking medical physiology and of course, none of the equations are properly explained. The closest I've been able to get is [this page](https://journals.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/advan.00064.2019). Even here however, steps from equations 14 to equation 15 is waved away as "careful algebraic manipulations").

What exacly is happening here?

We start with

$$RQ=\frac{\frac{F_ACO_2}{1-F_IO_2-F_ACO_2}}{\frac{F_IO_2}{1-F_IO_2}-\frac{F_AO_2}{1-F_AO_2-F_ACO_2}}$$

and we're supposed to end up with:

$$F_AO_2=F_IO_2-F_ACO_2(F_IO_2+\frac{(1-F_IO_2)}{RQ})$$

What I've done so far is to try to isolate $F_AO_2$ on one side, so:

$$RQ=\frac{\frac{F_ACO_2}{1-F_IO_2-F_ACO_2}}{\frac{F_IO_2}{1-F_IO_2}-\frac{F_AO_2}{1-F_AO_2-F_ACO_2}}$$

$$=>\frac{F_IO_2}{1-F_IO_2}-\frac{F_AO_2}{1-F_AO_2-F_ACO_2}=\frac{\frac{F_ACO_2}{1-F_IO_2-F_ACO_2}}{RQ}$$

$$=>-\frac{F_AO_2}{1-F_AO_2-F_ACO_2}=\frac{\frac{F_ACO_2}{1-F_IO_2-F_ACO_2}}{RQ}-\frac{F_IO_2}{1-F_IO_2}$$

$$=>\frac{F_AO_2}{1-F_AO_2-F_ACO_2}=\frac{F_IO_2}{1-F_IO_2}-\frac{F_ACO_2}{(1-F_IO_2-F_ACO_2)RQ}$$

$$=>F_AO_2=\frac{F_IO_2*(1-F_AO_2-F_ACO_2)}{1-F_IO_2}-\frac{F_ACO_2(1-F_AO_2-F_ACO_2)}{(1-F_IO_2-F_ACO_2)RQ}$$

From here I'm however not sure how to proceed. I have tried to run this both with chatGPT and with Gemini, but neither seems to return useful results.

Comment: I'm assuming a few places where you have $F_1 O_2$ you really mean $F_I O_2$?

Comment: Well yes, that would be a typo on my part

Comment: fixed that, then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have made a copying mistake, the correct formula is:

$$RQ=\frac{\frac{F_{A_{CO_2}}}{1-F_{A_{O_2}}-F_{A_{CO_2}}}}{\frac{F_{I_{O_2}}}{1-F_{I_{O_2}}}-\frac{F_{A_{O_2}}}{1-F_{A_{O_2}}-F_{A_{CO_2}}}}$$

Pay attention to the denominator of the numerator.

Let's simplify the formula somewhat:

$$RQ=\frac{F_{A_{CO_2}}}{\frac{F_{I_{O_2}}}{1-F_{I_{O_2}}}({1-F_{A_{O_2}}-F_{A_{CO_2}}})-F_{A_{O_2}}}$$

This you obtain by multiplying numerator and denominator by ${1-F_{A_{O_2}}-F_{A_{CO_2}}}$.

Then rearranging:

$$\frac{F_{I_{O_2}}}{1-F_{I_{O_2}}}({1-F_{A_{O_2}}-F_{A_{CO_2}}})-F_{A_{O_2}} = \frac{F_{A_{CO_2}}}{RQ} $$

Working out the left hand side, grouping terms containing $F_{A_{O_2}}$:

$$\frac{F_{I_{O_2}}}{1-F_{I_{O_2}}}({1-F_{A_{CO_2}}})-\frac{1}{1-F_{I_{O_2}}}F_{A_{O_2}} = \frac{F_{A_{CO_2}}}{RQ} $$

Multiplying both sides by $1-F_{I_{O_2}}$

$$F_{I_{O_2}}({1-F_{A_{CO_2}}})-F_{A_{O_2}} = (1-F_{I_{O_2}})\frac{F_{A_{CO_2}}}{RQ} $$

or after rearranging some more

$$F_{A_{O_2}} = F_{I_{O_2}}({1-F_{A_{CO_2}}}) - (1-F_{I_{O_2}})\frac{F_{A_{CO_2}}}{RQ}$$

and finally

$$F_{A_{O_2}} = F_{I_{O_2}}-F_{A_{CO_2}}\left(F_{I_{O_2}} + \frac{1-F_{I_{O_2}}}{RQ}\right) \; .$$

Answer (score 1):

## **The equation given is wrong.**

To make the equations easier to read, I will use the substitute symbols
$$a=RQ \\ b=F_ACO_2 \\ c=F_IO_2 \\ d=F_AO_2$$

Using which we can write your original equation as

### $$a=\frac{\frac{b}{1-c-b}}{\frac{c}{1-c}-\frac{d}{1-d-b}}\tag{1}$$

The equation we want to end up with is

### $$d=c-b\left(c+\frac{1-c}{a}\right)\tag{*}$$

If you ask Wolfram Alpha to solve $(1)$ for $d$, it [**ends up with**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve%5Ba%3D%3D%28%28b%29%2F%281-c-b%29%29%2F%28%28c%29%2F%281-c%29+-+%28d%29%2F%281-d-b%29%29%2Cd%5D)

### $$d=-\frac{(b-1)\big((a-1)bc+a(c-1)c+b\big)}{a(b+c-1)-bc+b}\tag{**}$$

If you then [**ask it**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=true+or+false+-%28%28-1+%2B+b%29+%28b+%2B+%28-1+%2B+a%29+b+c+%2B+a+%28-1+%2B+c%29+c%29%29%2F%28b+-+b+c+%2B+a+%28-1+%2B+b+%2B+c%29%29%3D%3Dc-b*%28c%2B%281-c%29%2F%28a%29%29) if this is equivalent to $(*)$, the answer is no , *in general*.

However $(**)$ and $(*)$ *will* be equivalent in the special cases

$$b=0~~\text{and}~~a\neq 0 ~~\text{and}~~1-c\neq 0 \\ \text{OR} \\ c=1~~\text{and}~~a\neq 0 ~~\text{and}~~b\neq 0 \\ \text{OR} \\ c=\frac{1}{1-a}~~\text{and}~~a-1\neq 0~~\text{and}~~a\neq 0~~\text{and}~~1-b\neq 0$$

---

My best guess is that you copied something down wrong, or there is some additional information we are missing.

Comment: The mistake seems to be in the denominator of the numerator, where instead of $c$, there should be $b$. You can find the correct formula in the article.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Please post this as an answer.